# Get the count through iterate over Data Bag but condition should be different count for each value associated to that field

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

> Below is the data I have and the **schema** for the same is-
>   **student_name, question_number, actual_result(either - false/Correct)**

```
(b,q1,Correct)
(a,q1,false)
(b,q2,Correct)
(a,q2,false)
(b,q3,false)
(a,q3,Correct)
(b,q4,false)
(a,q4,false)
(b,q5,flase)
(a,q5,false)
```

> What I want is to get the count for each student i.e. a/b for total
>   correct and false answer he/she has made.

Comment: What is the expected output ? Currently in answers, you see two kinds of output. 1. student -- correct_ans_count -- incorrect_ans_count 2. student -- actual_result(correct/false) -- count. Based on your use case add the expected output and accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the use case shared, below pig script is suffice.

**Pig Script :**

```
student_data = LOAD 'student_data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (student_name:chararray, question_number:chararray, actual_result:chararray);
student_data_grp = GROUP student_data BY student_name;
student_correct_answer_data = FOREACH student_data_grp {
    answers = student_data.actual_result;
    correct_answers = FILTER answers BY actual_result=='Correct';
    incorrect_answers = FILTER answers BY actual_result=='false';
    GENERATE group AS student_name, COUNT(correct_answers) AS correct_ans_count, COUNT(incorrect_answers) AS incorrect_ans_count ;
};
```

**Input : student_data.csv :**

```
b,q1,Correct
a,q1,false
b,q2,Correct
a,q2,false
b,q3,false
a,q3,Correct
b,q4,false
a,q4,false
b,q5,false
a,q5,false
```

**Output : DUMP kpi:**

```
-- schema : (student_name, correct_ans_count, incorrect_ans_count)
(a,1,4)
(b,2,3)
```

**Ref :** For more details on nested FOR EACH

1. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#foreach
2. http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch06.html#more_on_foreach

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
data = LOAD '/abc.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, number:chararray,result:chararray);
B = GROUP data by (name,result);
C = foreach B generate FLATTEN(group) as (name,result), COUNT(data) as count;
```

and answer will be like:

```
(a,false,4)
(a,Correct,1)
(b,false,3)
(b,Correct,2)
```

Hope this is the output you are looking for